# Windows 7 like form style in c#(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

hai am develping a application in c#(WPF). when i run the application in windows xp, i want to show windows like how we look in windows 7 or in vista..
 am using WPF with c#. is it possible. how can i do

Comment: Why? I hate it when apps do this. Stick with a predictable UI that the user understands - the one that his current OS uses.

Comment: yes matt, i too hate. but client requirement, what shall i do.. :)

Comment: You want transparency etc? If it's even possible, I imagine it'll be a LOT of work.

Comment: yes, windows7 like title bar, minimize, close button like that, for example, if u open skype in windows xp, it will looks like windows7 default form style, like that,. how it works in skype form design.???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's late, but I'm post something here that can help other people.

This can be a start:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="rectangle1" Stroke="#111111" Fill="#dd334455" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" />
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="1" BorderBrush="#ddffffff" CornerRadius="5" />
        <Label Content="Window title">
            <Label.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="White" BlurRadius="10" />
            </Label.Effect>
        </Label>
        <Grid Margin="8,25,8,8" Background="White">
            <Label Content="Controls here" />
        </Grid>
        <Border Margin="6,23,6,6" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#99ffffff" CornerRadius="1" />
        <Border Margin="7,24,7,7" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#333333" CornerRadius="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```